# Recover Visual Studio 2019 configurations

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I know that I can export/import VS configurations file, however, I've had an failure in my Windows and I reinstalled my Windows... So I had no chance to export the configuration file but I managed to backup my old files in drive C right before reinstalling my Windows . I know the configurations are somewhere there but have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio IDE settings will be stored in `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\` and `%appdata%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`